# detect Developer Setting 'do not keep activities'

Tags: java, android

How can I detect if a device has 'do not keep activities' set in developer options.
I can't find this value in the settings-class.

I need this setting to know, because when 'do not keep activities' is activated my app gets problem with it. 
Example : I have a main-activity and a sub-activity. when I switch from main to sub and back from sub to main, then the main-activity will be started again. This is because the mainactivity was killed before. besause I do a lot of loading in my main-activity, the app is not usable when starting over and over.

Or is there any method to solve this problem ?
Without this setting activated, there is no problem.

regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Is it possible to detect that flag by code ?

Yes.

In API Doc, it is called [Settings.System.ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES):

> If 1, the activity manager will aggressively finish activities and processes as soon as they are no longer needed. If 0, the normal extended lifetime is used.
>
> Constant Value: "always_finish_activities"

To get the value in code:

```
int value = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES, 0);
```

Check out the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/DevelopmentSettings.java#L624) to see how Settings.apk did this.

Comment: Hi yorkw
Thank you very much for your help. That is it what I searched for. Have a nice day !

Comment: @user1344545, glad to hear it helps:)

Comment: hi, how to un-check it programtically. Please help on this.

Comment: 2017 update: Replace `Settings.` with `Settings.Global.` because the former one has been deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can and as I answered to someone else, why would you want to? You certainly should not be using that flag to change the behavior of your app.

[Don't keep activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649949/how-to-know-dont-keep-activities-is-enabled-in-ics/11650249#11650249)

Comment: I do not want to change that flag I only want to detect that flag as the title says. Is it possible to detect that flag by code ?