# Enable "Dont keep activities" from Developer Options from command line or Espresso test case

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I want to test if the onCreate/onDestroy flow works fine when running my Espresso tests, and I can enable "Don't keep activities" from the developer options on the device manually but I can't find a way to do it on remote devices, like firebase test farm.

Is there any way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Like here [How to know "Don't keep activities" is enabled in ICS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11649949/10956936)
have you try this :

```
Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES,  1);
```

Comment: Thanks but I need `android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` for that and it says `this is only granted to system apps`, any other idea?